# Where is the 6th bit in 16-bit char value?

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

There are two examples of bit switching in the book *Java: A Beginners Guide*. In both cases, the author writes about switching the 6th bit but he demonstrates it on 16 digits. Both examples use bitwise operators for changing the letter case.

1. In the first, he operates on lower case characters: `'a' & 65503` changes the char to `'A'`. It is described as switching the 6th bit off. The problem is the number `65503` equals `1111 1111 1101 1111` in binary. Hence the 11th digit/bit is switched off (he even shows the number there).
2. The same he does for uppercase letters and bitwise OR operator: `'a' | 32` does the trick. The number 32 equals `0000 0000 0010 0000` in binary.

In both cases, the change does make sense. I just don’t understand why the author writes about the 6th bit. I would understand if it was for the 11th bit or 6th pair (in that case I would expect the turning it off completely as `00` or `11`.

Any clarification more than welcome.

Comment: Count from the right.

Comment: You count from the least significant bit, ie from right to left.

Comment: there are some weirdos like IBM who count bits from the left, but generally bits are counted from the least significant bit up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 0's and 1's that make up a binary number are called bits. The bits start from the right and go left:

So `0010 0000`:

```
8th bit  7th bit  6th bit  5th bit  4th bit  3rd bit  2nd bit  1st bit
0        0        1        0        0        0        0        0
```

Decimal is read the same way as binary:

`3754` in decimal:

```
(3 x 1000) | (7 x 100) | (5 x 10) | (4 x 1)
```

`156` in binary = `10011100`

```
(1 x 128)|(0 x 64)|(0 x 32)|(1 x 16)|(1 x 8)|(0 x 4)|(0 x 2)|(0 x 1)
```

In decimal you add a new column to to the start of the number (i.e the right) when you reach a power of 10.

In binary you add a new column when you reach a power of 2.

Does this help explain it?

Comment: Please, it would be great if you added a bit :) more. According to @daniu (the comment below my question), bit counting really starts from the right according to the bit's significance. I guess it is because the one on the very right has not to be multiplied by 2 to some power when doing the conversion back. Is that right? (+ The first sentence about 0's and 1' is removable here, I think.)

Answer (score 3):

The location of the 6th bit could be in a few locations, depending upon the convention you adopt:

1. Counting the left-most bit as zero-th, and moving right
2. Counting the left-most bit as first, and moving right
3. Counting the right-most bit as zero-th, and moving left
4. Counting the right-most bit as first, and moving left
5. (Other conventions may be available)

The author should really have defined which of these he was using, for clarity (and may do, elsewhere in the text). But apparently, he means item 4.

```
0000 0000 0010 0000
            65 4321
```

Comment: Only 3 and 4 are ever used in practice, since changing the word size doesn't change the bit index.